# Exotic Cell Shapes

Tags: cell-biology, plant-anatomy

As far as I know, plant cell shapes are a difficult thing to pin down. However plant cells have cell walls and so can be very rigid. However the only plant cells I've seen have been either block shaped or tube shaped. Are there more exotic examples of cell shapes, particularly in plants? For instance have plants ever used honeycomb patterns or other forms of tesselation?

Answer (score 1):

Pavement cells should content you:
[image]

From http://dev.biologists.org/content/131/21/5215.full